# In my NodeJS program, why is my array not defined

Tags: node.js

I have a file clothingParse,js where I am setting up the code to find the data on a site page.
Here is the code.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');

const clothingParse = function (url) {
    return rp(url)
        .then(function (html) {
            return {
                cItem: $('.lvtitle', html).text(),
                cPrice: $('.lvsubtitle', html).text(),
            };
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            //handle error
            console.log("Failed")
        });
};

module.exports = clothingParse;
```

Here is the code in my main program that will get the data from clothingParse.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const clothingParse = require('./clothingParse.js');


const url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_udlo=&_udhi=&_ftrt=903&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=15&_stpos=98126&_dmd=1&_ipg=200&_fosrp=1&_nkw=brunello+cucinelli&_sop=10';

rp(url)
    .then(function (html) {
        //success!

        const BCItems = [];
        BCItems[0] = "Testing";
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //console.log(i, BCItems[i], BCItems[i].length);
            BCItems.push($('big > a', html)[i].attribs.href);       //error here
        }
        return Promise.all(
            BCItems.map(function(url) {
                return clothingParse(url);
            })
        );
    })
    .then(function (clothing) {
        console.log(clothing);
           //console.log($('.lvsubtitle', html).text());
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        //handle error
        console.log(err)
    });
```

Here is the error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribs' of undefined on the push line marked //error here.

Comment: At first glance I'd say that `big` has something to do with it... that's an obsolete tag and I doubt that ebay would actually use that in their markup. Loading the page on my browser, the output of `document.querySelectorAll('big')` seems to agree with my guess.

Comment: I think cheerio works exactly like jquery and you won't need html as the second parameter: $('big > a') should do.

Comment: What do you see when you console log `$('big > a', html)` ?

Comment: @P.B.UDAY that's not correct. Looking at [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio), the usage of cheerio here is correct (note `Optionally, you can also load in the HTML by passing the string as the context`)

Comment: My clothingParcer returns the two variables: cItem and cPrice.
In the main program, in the push line, how are the passed in variables referenced?